# error: expected type-specifier before ‘Elem’

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm trying to use Template Inheritance to implement a data structure, and when I try to insert an element, it gives the following error:

> pilha.h:15:21: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Elem’
>
> > this->topo = new Elem(dado);

and several other errors related to it.

The code:

base.h

```
#ifndef __BASE_H_INCLUDED__
#define __BASE_H_INCLUDED__ 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Base {
protected:
    class Elem;
public:

    Base(){
        tam = 0;
    }
    virtual ~Base(){
        if (tam == 0) return;
        for(Elem *aux = topo; aux != NULL; aux = aux->ant) {
            Elem *aux2 = aux;
            delete(aux2);
        }
    }
    bool vazia(){
        return tam == 0;
    }
    unsigned int tamanho(){
        return tam;
    }
    virtual T retira() = 0;
    virtual void imprime(){
    if(tam == 0) {
        cout << "A " << nome_da_classe << " esta vazia!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "Impressao = ";
    for(Elem *aux = topo; aux != 0; aux = aux->ant) {
        cout << aux->dado << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
    T ver_topo(){
    if (tam == 0) {
        cout << "A " << nome_da_classe << " esta vazia!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return topo->dado;
}
protected:
    int tam;
    class Elem{
    public:
        T dado;
        Elem *prox;
        Elem *ant;
        Elem(T d){
            dado = d;
        }
    };
    Elem *topo;
    Elem *base;
    string nome_da_classe;
};
#endif
```

base.cpp

```
#include "base.h"
```

pilha.h

```
#ifndef __PILHA_H_INCLUDED__
#define __PILHA_H_INCLUDED__ 
#include "base.h"

template <class T> 
class Pilha : public Base<T> {
public:
    Pilha(){
        this->topo = nullptr;
        this->nome_da_classe = "Pilha";
    }
    ~Pilha(){}
    void insere(T dado){
        if (!this->tam) {               
            this->topo = new Elem(dado);
            this->topo->ant = nullptr;
        } else {
            Elem *elem = new Elem(dado);
            elem->ant = this->topo;
            this->topo = elem;
        }
        this->tam++;
    }
    T retira(){
        if (this->tam == 0) {
            cout << "A "<< this->nome_da_classe << " esta vazia!" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        T aux = this->topo->dado;
        Elem *aux2 = this->topo;
        this->topo = this->topo->ant;               
        delete(aux2);
        this->tam--;
        return aux;         
    }
};

#endif
```

pilha.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "base.h"
#include "pilha.h"
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pilha.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {

    Pilha<int> *b = new Pilha<int>();
    b->imprime();
    b->insere(5);
    delete(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Any opinion will be really helpful.

Comment: There's no such class called `Elem`, which is what the compiler is telling you. There is an inner class `Elem`, that's a member of a template class, but that's nothing to do with the `Elem` class a completely unrelated template is trying to reference. Oh, and you should also [get rid of `using namespace std;` and completely forget that it exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Just because there's an inner class in template class doesn't mean that you can just reference it directly from another class. C++ doesn't work this way.

Comment: Note that your attempt at safe destruction in `~Base()` isn't safe at all, since `aux` still points to the deleted object.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You make it sound like the problem is it's an inner class.  But this would be entirely legal if we inherited, say `Base<int>` rather than `Base<T>`.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I reckon `Elem` is not recognised as type. Either qualify it (`Base::Elem`) or declare an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Members of a dependent base class (a base class whose type depends on one or more template parameters) are not found by ordinary name lookup.  You need to spell out `typename Base<T>::Elem`:

```
this->topo = new typename Base<T>::Elem(dado);
```

Comment: so I use typename to explain to my compiler that "Base<T>::Elem" is a type?

Comment: Yes. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords